# Creating subdirectories documentation in a single doxygen page (VHDL)

Tags: doxygen

I'm trying to document VHDL base code of my company which is segmented by subdirectories containing 1 module reusable for our projects.

One module can contain a lot of VHDL files, so with a lot of modules, the documentation becomes really hard to read. I want to organize my documentation per module into a single page. Every module is independent to each other.
Do you know a solution to do this? The /addgroup command is close from I want to achieve but doesn't show the hierarchy as "Design unit Hierarchy" does.

It is not documented on doxygen.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Can you give a small example (probably 2 files will do) together with the doxygen settings used (different from the default settings i.e. `doxygen -x Doxyfile`) that shows the problem.

Comment: I'm using Doxygen 1.9.6 and my doxyfile has default settings except OPTIMIZE_FOR_VHDL. 
It will be easier to explain by image what I'm trying to do.
I have 2 directories IP_1 and IP_2. Both are independants and contains a lot of files: https://ibb.co/61KtY6Q
I want doxygen to organize the hierarchy like this : https://ibb.co/gyxxkjK
and not flatten, cause of number of files it's not really readable.

Comment: Please edit the images in the question, the external site might not be trustworthy / persistent.